# Tidy URLs, Query Strings and force type not working as expected

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im trying to make my site URLS 'tidy' and can't figure out querystrings

example, I want:

```
services.php?service=3
```

to be

```
services/3
```

I have the appropriate code in my services page to get the item

```
$loc = explode("/",$HTTP_SERVER_VARS["REQUEST_URI"]);
$service = $loc[count($loc)-1];
```

and htaccess is set to do all the redirect work on .php files as well as

```
<FilesMatch "^services$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

but "services/3" gets a 404 error.
```

Rewrite rules being used are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php\ HTTP   
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^services/([0-9]+)(/)?$ services.php?service=$1
```

Comment: While that technically works, the URL is tidy, but links to external files are lost - everything now going to "/services/services/*filename links to the CSS and other linked files lost too.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be affected. Only [0-9] only allows numbers, not slashes or letters